# Помочь переписать с C++ Builder на СИ.

Tags: c++builder, c

Здравствуйте!

Вся суть описана тут:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread1093527.html

Если можете, пишите тут, свяжемся. Оплатить работу готов. Делаем параллельно, по скайпу или почте и т.д.
Т.е. Вы говорите, я делаю.

Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что 1) это не вопрос, а предложение выполнить работу, 2) по ссылкам хоть и можно найти подробности, но они могут стать неактуальными, 3) результат не предполагается публиковать здесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что это не бредовая затея? Ну я еще понял бы переписать на Java или С#, но переписывать с С++ на С да еще и в консоль! Как это вы собираетесь графический интерфейс реализовывать в консоли? Не проще ли уделить пару дней и изучить основы С++, чем изобретать велосипед на С? Тем более, что эти 300 строк на плюсах, чтобы получить хотя бы похожий функционал перерастут не в щдну тысячу строк сишного кода

Comment: 1. Мне не нужен весь графический аппарата.
2. Мне нужны только математические модели.
3. Там с++ builder + очень убого написанный.
4. Строк это займёт меньше, т.к. не будет GUI.